# mapply - passing row and column of element as argument

Tags: r, mapply

I'm new to R programming and I know I could write a loop to do this, but everything I read says that for simplicity its best to avoid loops and use apply instead.

I have a matrix and i would like to run this function on each element in the matrix.

```
cellresidue <- function(i,j){
  result <- (cluster[i,j] - cluster.I[i,] - cluster.J[j,] - cluster.IJ)/(cluster.N*cluster.M)
  return (result)
}

i= element row
j= element column
cluster.J is a matrix of column means
cluster.I is a matrix of row means
cluster.IJ is the mean of the entire matrix named cluster
```

What I can't figure out is how do I get the row  and column of the element (I think should use row() and column col() functions) that mapply is working with and how do pass those arguments to mapply or apply?

Comment: There might be value to reading the code that is in `chisq.test` to see how the masters do a similar procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for loops or `*apply` functions. You can just use plain matrix operations:

```
nI <- nrows(cluster)
nJ <- ncols(cluster)
cluster.I  <- matrix(rowMeans(cluster), nI, nJ, byrow = FALSE)
cluster.J  <- matrix(rowMeans(cluster), nI, nJ, byrow = TRUE)
cluster.IJ <- matrix(    mean(cluster), nI, nJ)

residue.mat <- (cluster - cluster.I - cluster.J - cluster.IJ) /
               (cluster.N * cluster.M)
```

(You did not explain what `cluster.N` and `cluster.M` are but I assume they are scalars)

Comment: Could have skipped the `cluster.I` and `cluster.IJ` constructions and used `rowMeans(.)` and `mean(.)` and just used R argument recycling, but it's probably clearer the way you did it.

Comment: Yes, I prefer to make my code symmetric when I can so it is easier to read and maintain. Performance likely won't suffer. It's like these extra spaces that are not necessary, but that make everything cleaner, no?

Comment: Agree, clearer. Just trying to add a bit of knowledge that may come in handy when reading code by people who are more concerned with economy that clarity.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to calculate the residue of a matrix,  cluster.n and cluster.m are the number of rows and columns in the matrix.  I did not post data as I did not think that it was needed in this instance but will do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what you are trying to do. It is best on this site to provide some mock data (preferably generated by the code, not pasted), and then show what form the end result should look like. It seems that the `apply` family is not what you seek.

Quick disambiguation between apply, sapply and mapply:

```
#providing data for examples
X=matrix(rnorm(9),3,3)
```

**apply**: apply a function to either columns (2) or rows (1) of a matrix or array

```
#here, sum by columns, same as colSums(X)
apply(X, 2, sum)
```

**sapply**: apply a function against (usually) a list of objects

```
#create a list with three vectors
mylist=list(1:4, 5:10, c(1,1,1))
#get the mean of each vector
sapply(mylist, mean)

#remove 2 to each element of X, same as c(X-2)
sapply(X, FUN=function(x) x-2)
```

**mapply**: a multivariate version of sapply, taking an arbitrary number of arguments. Never had much use of it… Some rock-bottom examples:

```
#same as c(1,2,3,4) + c(15,16,17,18)
mapply(sum, 1:4, 15:18)

#same as c(X+X), the vectorized matrix sum
mapply(sum, X, X)
```

Side note: It's perfectly ok to use loops in R; use whichever suits the best your thoughts. The issue is that if you have a "really big" number of iterations, this is where you could meet bottlenecks, depending on your patience. There are two solutions to this: rewrite your function in C/FORTRAN (and boost speed), or use built-in functions if applicable (which are, by the way, often writen in C or FORTRAN).